# I have a new login form, how do I ensure that browsers autofill the username and password used on the previous login form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, autofill

We're upgrading ADFS on our servers (which causes the HTML markup to be completely different), and we want to make sure that after we switchover that users don't have to enter in their username and password. I've looked all over the place and can't find an answer regarding this particular scenario. How can I ensure that browsers still autofill the username and password on the new page?

All I can do is edit a script that gets executed on page load, which so far I've updated the names of the inputs to be the same as on the previous page, as well as set autocomplete="on" for the form and input elements, which works on FireFox, but not on Chrome or Edge. Do I need to set the id's of the inputs and/or form to be the same as the previous page as well? What all is necessary to make sure browsers still autofill on the new page?

Comment: If you are using javascript and its not working, the problem could be simply the browser's autocomplete is recognizing the fields BEFORE the javascript is ran.

Comment: Yeah that was my fear, unfortunately I can't update the markup at all due to ADFS's backend being a black box. Chrome and Edge suggest the username/password when you focus into the inputs (as opposed to autofilling them on page load which is what happened on the previous form), which I think suggests your theory is right